Suspenseful/thriller movie from the 00's about a group of parents that show up at a lake house and their college-aged sons are missing
I watched a film a few years back, I would say sometime between 2009-2014 on Netflix. I thought for sure it starred Alec Baldwin, but searching through his IMDb film list, I can't find anything matching this film. I also checked his brothers' IMDbs as well. 
The film I believe starts off with a college boy going over to one of his wealthy friend's vacation or lake house homes. They are all driving in a convertible with other friends. I want to say they've all been friends since childhood and there may have been some tension between a few of them. 
The friends arrive at the home and something happens-- I am not even sure the audience sees it, I just know some one gets murdered or goes missing. 
Cut to later that day or the next day and all the boy's dads are there looking for them or something. I think a cop might show up as well. The dads are all worried for their sons and end up starting to blame each other. 
We soon find out that one of the son's and his dad are in on it and it's some big twist. I think some flashbacks may be shown. I believe their family is poor while the rest of the dads are rich. 
I remember some of the kids running through the woods running away from the son who was in on it. 
The film could have been made anywhere between 2002-2014 and I'm pretty sure it was an Indie film or one that flew under the radar. 

Hi. Please add the identify-this-movie tag to ID questions. Also, are you looking for this (The Entitled from 2011)?

Yes, that looks like that is it! Thank you! Sorry for the late response.
